# How to add another page to an UIScrollView by swiping?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I am a french 17 years old guy so excuse my english.

I am creating an app' using an UIScrollView with an UIPageControl to display multiple UIView pages from UIViewControllers (which display an object) . Everything works pretty great.

Now i would like to add a new page (and a new empty object but that is not a problem) when I swipe the UIScrollView to the right in the last view.

How could I do that ? And if it's not possible, how can I update the UIScrollView ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to keep an eye on two things. `scrollViewDidScroll:` & `UIPageControl`'s `currentPage`. When you determine that the user is currently viewing the rightmost page & the `UIScrollView` was scrolled, you can add a new page to the `UIPageControl`. The amount by which the scroll view was scrolled is related to `scrollView.contentOffset.x`. A new page can be added to the page control by incrementing its `numberOfPages` & setting the `currentPage` to the newest page.

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's not perfect but I manage to make another page thanks to the 'contentOffset' property ! I check it and then I reload the page !

Comment: What's remaining that makes it less than perfect?

Comment: I think the easiest thing you can do is to add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the scroll view (to detect that the user swiped) & add the 2nd page. Make sure that you only add the recognizer when there is a single page & remove it when you have more than one page.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for I think : a sample code from Apple to build a photo viewer that load images just before they appear on screen.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080